# Concatenate size_t and char* in C

Tags: c

```
size_t sz = 100;
char* length[3] = "LEN";
```

How to concatenate size_t and char*?

The result I want is something like

```
char* length = "100LEN"
```

Not just print out "100LEN".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you wish `length` to be a *string*, space for the null terminator is needed; `char length[4] = "LEN";`, or better, `char length[] = "LEN";`, to ensure this. Alternatively, `length` could be a pointer to a string literal: `char *length = "LEN";`.

You can use `sprintf()` to build a string like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t sz = 100;
    char *length = "LEN";
    char result[7];

    sprintf(result, "%zu%s", sz, length);

    printf("%s\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

The `result` buffer must be large enough to contain the characters written by `sprintf()`. If there is uncertainty about sizes involved, it is safer to use `snprintf()` (since C99). The return value of this function is negative if there was an error in the function call, otherwise it is the number of characters that would have been written to an appropriately sized buffer, less the null terminator. This return value could be used to check to see if output was truncated, or could be used to allocate a buffer of the correct size.

The latter approach is illustrated in the below code. First, `snprintf()` is called to write zero characters to a null pointer target. The return value, `n`, is the number of characters that would have been written to an appropriately sized buffer. This value could be used to declare a VLA, but this array could not be resized later if needed again; here `malloc()` is used to allocate space, including space for the null terminator. If the `result` buffer is needed again, it can be reallocated to a new size. This memory must be deallocated before exiting the program.

Note that the return value of `snprintf()` is checked for errors. The return value of `malloc()` is also checked for errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t sz = 100;
    char *length = "LEN";
    int n;

    n = snprintf(NULL, 0,"%zu%s", sz, length);
    if (n < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in snprintf() size evaluation\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Could use a VLA, but this cannot be resized */
//    char result[n+1];

    /* Using malloc() allows result to be reallocated later if necessary */
    size_t result_sz = n + 1;
    char *result = malloc(result_sz);
    if (result == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    n = snprintf(result, result_sz, "%zu%s", sz, length);
    if (n < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in snprintf() write\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%s\n", result);

    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
100LEN
```

Comment: Perhaps you got the downvote because "*You need space for the null terminator if you use an array*" as if taken literally it's not true.

Comment: @alk-- Perhaps. That seems a petty reason for a downvote, as I think the meaning was clear. But, point taken, and that could have been worded better. I have updated my answer, and added comments about use of `snprintf()`. My suspicion is that DVs were a kneejerk reaction to my using `sprintf()`.

Comment: `if (n > 100) {` is confusing - especially as it uses magic number 100 and has nothing to do with the 100 in `size_t sz = 100;`.  This test appears to be an unnecessary sanity test.  Recommend deleting or explaining its usefulness.

Comment: @chux-- boy, you are right, that was confusing. This answer is old enough that I am a little fuzzy on what my original thinking was, but I think that I was just trying to provide an escape hatch if input, e.g., user input, was maliciously long. I should try to write less confusing code! Removed. Thanks for the catch; this may have been the reason for the DVs.

Comment: @chux-- Looking at this again, I see that I had written: "Note that the return value of `snprintf()` is checked for errors, _and for unreasonably high return values indicating that the input is not as expected_" just before the code in my answer. Still, this was quite unclear in the code; I think I have now removed all traces of this silliness....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate a compile-time integer constant with a string literal, the problem is reduced to stringifying the integer constant at the preprocessor level, given that the preprocessor automatically concatenates string literals that are adjacent:

```
#define SZ 100
#define MYSTR "LEN"
int main()
{

#define _STR(X) #X
#define STR(X)  _STR(X)


    puts(STR(SZ) MYSTR);

}
```

If any of the two components is not known at compile time, you'll need a (sufficiently large) buffer to write the result into, and you'll need to convert the number to a string yourself, e.g., with `sprintf`:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>


int main()
{

size_t sz = 100;
char const *str = "len";

char concat[40+strlen(str)+1];
assert(sizeof(size_t)*CHAR_BIT <= 128);
//40 is sufficiently large for up to 128 bit size_t's
//given that log_10(2^128) == 38

    sprintf(concat, "%zu%s", sz, str);
    puts(concat);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use `sprintf()` it's unsafe and risks buffer overwrites.**

Always use `snprintf()` and allocate the maximum space that your output could be based on the sizes of the type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    size_t sz = 100;
    const char length[] = "LEN";

    const size_t buffersz=24;//On 64-bit platform covers a 20 digit size, 2 characters of "LEN" and the '\0' terminator.
    char buffer[buffersz];


    int count=snprintf(buffer,buffersz,"%zu%s",sz,length);

    printf("%d  %s",count,buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Footnote: Why you should never use `sprintf`.

It's suggested that it's OK to use `sprintf` so long as you know the input 
sizes.

It's still a risk and well written programs don't use it anymore.
It always risks some change in some other part of the program that changes output sizes. That's a classic downstream calamity. Change in an int to a long (or from 32 to 64 bit...) and **Boom**.

It's deprecated by the standard not just for user input but all input for good reason. Or maybe you just got a sum wrong and the program fails in obscure circumstances when a number of variables are near their limit.

Suppose a log message prints out a user name a date and a size and a sleeping bug that the buffer is just too short. Depending on your date format you might have a bug that only crashes for certain users at certain times of the month!
Don't use `sprintf()`. There's really no point worrying about. Just don't use it.

Comment: I disagree. It always risks some change in some other part of the program that changes output sizes. That's a classic downstream calamity. Change in an int to a long (or from 32 to 64 bit...) and *Boom*. 
It's deprecated by the standard not just for user input but all input for good reason.

Comment: @DavidBowling: It's deprecated in C++ not C. But the risks highlighted apply as much to C. Truncated output is on the whole considered better than no output (buffer overwrites typically result in a crash) and is easier to debug. if you're being real safe you check the return value of `snprintf` and either issue a log about truncation or reallocate the buffer and go again.
I never suggested robust programming was just using those functions but it definitely involves using those functions where available.

Comment: @PSkocik A static assert can be difficult or impossible if you're handling a string (which may be any length) or outputting `double` which have unclear 'maximum' output lengths. The overhead of counting is ultimately fairly trivial and as you point out pretty small compared to the inefficiencies of `printf`-style format strings.

Answer (score -2):

Once you fix all your other problems with the code above, use `sprintf()` (or, with the necessary changes, `snprintf()` if you have a C99 compiler)

```
sprintf(dst, "%d%s", (int)sz, string);
/* make sure dst has enough space */
```